# Add symbols to alphanumeric check with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this code to check if a String has non alphanumeric characters:

```
private boolean checkNonAlphanumeric(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
    return p.matcher(text).find();
}
```

This works fine. But now I need to check this adding some symbols. In this case "-". What pattern should I use in this case?

ABCabc-ABC1234 = should be OK.
a!#$%# = should be error.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add the character to the end? Like `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
private boolean checkNonAlphanumeric(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-]");
    return p.matcher(text).find();
}
```

I would suggest to add the double slash just to be sure that if in the future you change the regular expression, the - will continue to be interpreted in the right way.

If you use only - and then you decide to add other characters before or after the -, it won't work. For example:

```
private boolean checkNonAlphanumeric(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9<->]");
    return p.matcher(text).find();
}
```

Will not match the -, but the following code will work:

```
private boolean checkNonAlphanumeric(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9<\\->]");
    return p.matcher(text).find();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For only alphanumeric and the `-` use this:

```
private boolean checkNonAlphanumeric(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-]*");
    return p.matcher(text).find();
}
```